# mapping number of days a site is flooded from daily inundated areas maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a set of daily inundated area polygons and would like combine them into one map that can give me a map showing the number of days a site remained inundated.

I have ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Do a spatial join
Use the sites as your target features. Use the inundation polygons (all days in one feature class) as your join features.

If your sites are polygons or lines, the inundation polygon for each day must be a single multipart polygon.

If your sites are points, then you only need to make sure that there is no overlap between inundation polygons representing a day.

When you do your spatial join, the join count will be the number of days the site was inundated. You will not need any other results from the join.

Comment: Thanks Blord I shall try that but I would also like to know if its possible for rasters also? Regards

Comment: The sites are polygons or the inundation areas? Either way, you can use the same process starting with a raster to polygon conversion, but I think there might be other ways available to, perhaps using sample?